Python3 can't upgrade to the latest version with the brew command
"brew upgrade python3" returns "python not installed".
I have installed the Python 3!
Running Python 3 was feasible, however, upgrading to the newest version is not an option.

What is your system? MacOS, Linux, Windows?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@CharlesKnell Homebrew is, at least at this time, a package manager specific to macOS (though it's not a first-party tool).

@Jules, to be fair, you can use it on Linux now/WSL on Windows - https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

@CodeByAidan news to me, good to know for future reference. Thanks for finding that link.

TL;DR: I recommend using something like pyenv to manage system Python versions because of path conflicts. You can look into this tool at its official Github repo here.

What's most likely happening here is that while Homebrew did install the Python version you wanted, this version is preceded by the stock macOS Python in your $PATH in the shell you're using.
To remedy this, you have a few options:

Move your Homebrew install path up in your PATH. You can find out what that path is by running brew shellenv and looking for HOMEBREW_CELLAR. Typically, it's /usr/local/Cellar.
In this approach you'd make it so that /usr/local/Cellar is closer to the front of your PATH as defined in your shell config. How close to the front is circumstantial; you might have stuff in there that you specifically want to override Homebrew packages.

Use a tool like pyenv to manage installed Python versions. pyenv uses a shim to prioritize its managed Python versions in your PATH; canonically, this one gets added right up front in your PATH, or at least, ahead of any other PATH entry that'd contain a Python version. This approach has wide cross-platform support, it's fairly widely adopted (despite being an unofficial project relative to Python proper), and it's also agnostic of your project's package manager (pip vs poetry vs pipenv vs uv vs easy_install, if that's still something you're using).
pyenv will also respect project-specific, local Python versions if your project has a .python-version file (assuming you've installed that version of Python with pyenv).

Delegate to your project's Python package manager. Some package managers, like pipenv and poetry, will try to automate (or at least, wrap) what pyenv does. How this works exactly will depend on your project's package manager, and should be documented in their online or local docs.


